# Cannot create a Cloud Build trigger with Cloud Build repositories 2nd gen - permissions error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have been following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/github/connect-repo-github?generation=2nd-gen to create a Cloud Build Trigger from a GitHub repo connected to Cloud Build repositories 2nd gen.

Whether I use gcloud as in the instructions, use the Google Cloud Console UI or even try programmatically via Terraform, I get the same error.

I cannot work out if I need to set permissions somewhere or if it is just a misleading error and something is wrong with the GitHub permissions. My user account has the `roles/cloudbuild.connectionAdmin` role. I cannot see why the mentioned permission would not be there.

```
connection of repository projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/connections/my-app-github-connection/repositories/MyApp cannot be fetched: generic::permission_denied: Permission 'cloudbuild.connections.get' denied on 'projects/my-project-number/locations/us-central1/connections/my-app-github-connection'
```

Here is the roles the Cloud Build service account has granted:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the [Cloud Build service account permission](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#service-account-permissions-settings) page? Make sure that the service account email should be `[projectNumber]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: A comment, you dont need to be so permissive. Create a role `cloudbuild.connections.get` and attach to the service account. Besides, are you a GitHub admin ? In my case the problem was permission in GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, I had to enable Secret Manager Secret Accessor on the screen below.

I had been adding permissions to :

`service-262018307079@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

rather than:

`262018307079@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`.

[image]